# ubuntu package repository backup problem

Tags: package-management

I want to install new ubuntu 11.04 released yesterday, and my system currently has ubuntu 10.10. I have installed many packages related to my college project after 10.10 installation. Is there any script/code to find which packages I have installed after linux installation or packages other than default so that I can install them in new ubuntu version in one chance rather than on requirements again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a little script, some times ago, to obtain what you ask. Yes, the output should be refined, but it gives you a good hint to what you need (`aptitude` is required).

It essentially takes all packages installed not automatically *after* the end of the installation of the system, conventionally marked by the `grub-pc` package installation.

```
#!/bin/bash

export LC_COLLATE=C

eval $(lesspipe)

vars=($(less /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | 
  grep 'status installed grub-pc' | head -1))
date="${vars[0]}"
time="${vars[1]}"

join \
  <(aptitude -F%p search '?installed?not(?automatic)' |
    sort) \
  <(less /var/log/dpkg.log* |
    sort |
    awk -v date=$date -v time=$time '(($1 == date && $2 > time) || $1 > date) 
      && $3 == "install" { print $4 }' |
    sort -u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just [directly upgrade](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade) your 10.10 installation to 11.04? It'll automatically upgrade all of the packages you've added.

Comment: @WhiteFang I have read on many forums that currently its not safe to directly upgrade so first take backup all of your data first. So I don't wanna take risk for it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. I broke a few Ubuntu installs that way, and was too lazy to fiddle with Xorg and GRUB to fix it.

Comment: Really? We've upgraded tons of systems directly without any problems. I have seen problems in the past, and yeah it can be a pain to workaround them. It would be safest to backup and reinstall, so I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/cache/apt/archives` contains packages installed through repository.